# How to make multiple lists scroll as one (like a spreadsheet) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

What I'm trying to achieve, is to have a matrix, of say 1000x1000 or larger, to be scrollable both **vertically** and **horizontally**.
Also, it needs to be able to lazy load content both vertically and horizontally. Example:

[image]

Now, I've tried building this layout with `ListView`s of `ListView`s, however, the requirement that all of the horizontal `ListView`s need to be scrollable simultaneously is not satisfied in this way.

I've also tried a `CustomScrollView` with `SliverList`, however, I was unable to achieve anything with this approach either.

What am I missing, and how should such a scrolling problem be approached?

---

**Edit**

So far it seems like Flutter doesn't have a "native" way of achieving this kind of behavior yet. The challenges of 2D scrolling are better explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDZ0LPQq-n8&t=2s).

Also, there's this [Github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/87370) tracking the 2D scroll feature.

Comment: better you can use Table widget

Comment: @gowthamanC the thing is, I don't want it to be limited to only cells, because there will be other use cases when other types of widgets will need to be displayed in this kind of grid

Comment: Plus, seems like table isn't meant to be scrollable and it renders all it's children all at once

Comment: https://github.com/crizant/flutter_multiplication_table

Comment: @gowthamanC this isn't a lazily loaded list, [all the cells are pre-generated](https://github.com/crizant/flutter_multiplication_table/blob/4c34c527214bc678a64f8e875e5bffa77f17864f/lib/table_body.dart#L67-L88) which is very costly